# C# Is possible to give a relative path in SaveAsFile method?

Tags: c#, selenium

Is possible to give relative path to C # method SaveAsFile in Selenium ? I'm doing a project for my class and my local path is different than my teacher local path so i need to give relative path, but in every article about this method authors shows only absolute path.

My Code:

```
ITakesScreenshot tss = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot ss = tss.GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile("{{Here i tried to put relative path}}", ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Thank you, for you help!

Comment: why not? it should go to the current working directory - or you could use `Environment.GetFolderPath` to find something more reasonable

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ss.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "screenshot.jpeg"), ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

With this you save the screenshot to `bin\Debug\net6.0\screenshot.jpeg`